# Different layouts on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two main.xml files in layout-land and layout-port folders and when the orientation of the phone changes it forces a reload of main.xml.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration configure){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(configure);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

It works fine in portrait but pressing any of the imagebuttons on the page in landscape causes the app to crash. The imagebuttons all change an image called *grid* to a different image when pressed. The buttons that open another page work fine in both layouts. Here's a sample of the code.

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
// This is an imagebutton
findViewById(R.id.plank).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gridplanks);
            }
    });
// This is a button that brings up a new page
      findViewById(R.id.mcg).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                 startActivity(new Intent("com.example.minecraftcraftingguide.MCG"));
                 }
});
```

Is this what you need? New to programming, sorry.

```
>09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at com.example.minecraftcraftingguide.Menu$1.onClick(Menu.java:27)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-18 22:20:46.688: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I would recommend setting some break points, running it in debug mode and seeing what the cause of the crash actually is. I'm pretty sure that onCreate is called every time you rotate the device, so you should probably do all the work you're doing above in that instead.

Comment: Please show the logcat output, what error you are getting. Thanks.

Comment: My blind guess is that u remove this setContentView. Its not needed there. Follow instructions here for fast Configuration change http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Comment: Without stack trace it would be difficult to help you. Please paste your stacktrace here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a main.xml in your default layout folder or just the two in layout-port and layout-land?

If I were you, I would move the file from layout-port to your default layout folder. Then the app will use the file in layout-land if the app is in landscape folder, and otherwise (if the app is in portrait mode) will use the file in your default folder.

Another hint: Check the spelling in both xml files. Maybe you are missing a character in one of the button id's.

Comment: I moved the landscape-port main.xml to the default layout folder but now the all of the buttons don't work in landscape. The app doesn't crash, they just have no function. Also it won't switch back from landscape to portrait on orientation change.

Comment: Actually, I found a misspelling in the id in landscape mode, and the "stuck in landscape mode" problem I commented earlier is a known issue with the emulator apparently. It appears to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to decalare ConfigChanges in mainfest, and you dont need to write the setcontentView() in onOnfigurationChanged() method, infact, after declaring in mainfest , you dont need to write anything in your program, the android will automatically get the landscape xml file which resides in layout-land xml file.

Because whenever you call setContentView(), you have to declare its elements again.!!!

Just mention in the mainfest, in this activity tag android:configChanges=keyboardHidden|orientation
           or
Dont write anything in your onConfigChanged() method

Comment: It's not changing the xml file when I change the orientation. If I start the app in landscape, it loads the landscape file but it still crashes if I press a button.